# Is it possible to simulate a button press on an Android application from another application (Android or Desktop)?

Tags: android, button, automation, click

I need to automatically click on a specific button on an app. Is there a way to do this on a completely controlled environment?

By controlled environment, I mean the phone could be rooted, it could be connected to a desktop machine, any external app could be installed, and any other requirement.

Note: the button is NOT on an exposed activity.

Comment: What does "the button is NOT on an exposed activity" mean?

Comment: It means other applications are not allowed to start the button activity

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if the phone is connected to a desktop machine, you can install adb on the machine, connect the phone to the machine with a USB cable, and authorize the machine to access the phone by clicking "OK" on the prompt displayed on the phone. Having ensured that the path variable (assuming you're on Windows) contains the location of [adb.exe](http://adbshell.com/downloads), all you need to do is type the following in the terminal:

```
adb usb
adb shell input tap X Y
```

Where X and Y are the coordinates of the button. This should work if by "not exposed" you meant that "other applications are not allowed to start the button activity".

Answer (score 0):

In general: No it is not possible even from a rooted phone.
On special cases, when previously the  original app developer published a part of the code be callable from other app than that part of the code can be called, but you don't know if is equivalent or not with the button pressing. When you have this option and the luck to have it than you can call it. You can read more [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/index.html)